# Does Dragon's Breath break Sanctuary?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

We know that a familiar can use Dragon's Breath establishing it is not an attack, nor is it a spell being cast ([from this tweet](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/943256832969019393?lang=en)). Does that mean a familiar under the effects of Sanctuary could use Dragon's Breath without breaking its effect?

Answer (score 24):

## This was changed by errata, so *dragon's breath*'s action does break *sanctuary*

As of the [November 2018 Player's Handbook errata](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/errata-november-2018), *sanctuary* ends when:

> the warded creature makes an attack, casts a spell that affects an enemy, or deals damage to another creature

Hence, using the action granted by *dragon's breath* would end *sanctuary* as it deals damage to another creature.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87003/discussion-on-answer-by-david-coffron-does-dragons-breath-break-sanctuary).

Answer (score 1):

RAW you are correct.

However, [Jeremy Crawford](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/07/01/cast-witch-bolt-and-in-the-next-turn-cast-sanctuary-witch-bolt-cancel-sanctuary/) disagreed on Twitter in a ruling related to a spell with similar wording to *dragon's breath* for dealing damage:

> RAW: witch bolt exploits a loophole in sanctuary. RAI: witch bolt's damage ends sanctuary.

Casting *witch bolt* and then having *sanctuary* cast on you would make it harder for enemies to target you while still allowing you to do damage to enemies without ending *sanctuary*.

The *dragon's breath* spell would exploit a similar loophole. Crawford has explained that this is not the intent.

Comment: As of the current errata, the designers have closed this exploit.